# XPath, nested conditions

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have the following HTML code, and I need to have an XPath expression, which finds the table element.

```
<div>
   <div>Dezember</div>
   <div>
       <div class="dash-table-container">more divs</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My current Xpath expression:

`//div[./div[1]/text() = "Dezember"]/preceding::div[./div[2][@class=dash-table-container]`

I don't know how to check if the dash table container is the last one loaded, since I have many of them. So I need the check if it's under the div with "Dezember" as a text because the div's before with the other months are being loaded faster.
I want the XPATH to select the "dash table container" div.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `//div[preceding::div[text()="Dezember"]]`? `//div[preceding::div[text()="Dezember"] and @class="dash-table-container"]`?

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad that my comment helped. While it worked I find expressions from [zx485's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856308/10824407) more precise. Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

To select the `div` with the text content of "more divs", you can use

```
//div/div[@class="dash-table-container" and ../preceding-sibling::div[1]="Dezember"]
```

and to select its parent `div` element, use

```
//div[div/@class="dash-table-container"][preceding-sibling::div[1]="Dezember"]/..
```

Comment: Hello, your XPath expressions didn't work for me and I saw that there is another div I forgot to write. Could you please take a look again at it and tell me what I have to use as XPATH? Thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer to handle this new situation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

`//div[preceding-sibling::div="Dezember"]/div[@class="dash-table-container"]`

worked perfectly for me.